# Display Image Screen component in new Flow Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, customization

I was trying stuffs from Spring'19 release notes in prerelease org and found a new screen flow component to display the image:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_design_screencmp_address_and_image.htm?edition=&impact=

While checking this in org I got the configurable parameters in the right panel as shown in the image.

[image: Display Image in Flow Builder]

But there were some more parameters in the section named as "Store Output Values" (in red box) for the component which I didn't get what they were for. I searched for the documentation as well, but didn't get anything for v45.0 API. Anybody tried this and can explain?

Comment: did you able to figure out?

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper not yet, will check the docs again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters in Store Output Values are usually used when you have input fields in a Lightning component that you want to use elsewhere in your flow. For example, in the Phone screen component, you would need to set a resource variable in the Value field under Store Output Values if you wanted to use the value that the user input in that field. The Lightning components behave differently in this way than the native screen components (like Text), which you can just use the API name to get the value.

Unfortunately, due to the nature of how Flow handles Lightning components, when attributes are available for input they are also available for output. There's no way to designate them as only one or the other. So even though Display Image doesn't have a useful output, it *does* have some useful inputs, and consequently we get those in the output section as well.

Comment: yeah I understand the use of Output values in other cases like text, but not in case of Display Image, so I asked it here! :-)

Comment: Also found out, on questioning the developers, that the attributes available for input are always available for output - there's no way to turn them off if they don't make sense for output. I'll update my answer accordingly.